# How to add a color to labelText after it hovers to top left of textField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to give a different color to labelText after it hovers to top left of TextField.

```
 TextField(
              focusNode: mailFocusNode,
              onTap: () {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(mailFocusNode);
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "E-mail",
                labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                   borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                 ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  ),
                ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              controller: _controllerEmail,
              onChanged: (String value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _email = value;
                  });
                },
              ),
```

I expect a different color of LabelText when its on the TextField and when its hovering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your right, you want to change the color of label when `TextField` gets focus that means when `labelText` moves to the top left corner.

```
TextField(
  focusNode: mailFocusNode,
  onTap: () {
    _color = Colors.blue; // set your new Color
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(mailFocusNode);
    setState(() {});
  },
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: "E-mail",
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: _color),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
    ),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
    ),
  ),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
  controller: _controllerEmail,
  onChanged: (String value) {
    setState(() {
      _email = value;
    });
  },
)
```

Comment: thanks ... that was simple. That didn't clicked my mind maybe just due to lack of practice.
But i had to make many changes because it won't change back to original color if I left the focus of that TextField (If I left that textfield unedited).So many other minor adjustments had to be made.

Comment: Yes, you are right, you will have to handle color change again, a better way would be to do that in `FocusNode` listener. When in focus, change to Color A and when not change to Color B.